# keycloak Valid Redirect URIs for dynamic URLs w/ Vercel

Tags: keycloak, vercel

I'm setting up CI/CD to automatically deploy my application to a preview URL using vercel.com

these preview URLs are generated with a random string on every commit.

in keycloak if I add the entire string e.g. "https://c1-frontend-v4-anything.tet.vercel.app/"

I can login through keycloak fine. But no matter what I try I cannot get any wildcards to work...

I have tried:

- `https://*.vercel.app/`
- `https://*.vercel.app/*`
- `https://c1-frontend-v4-*.vercel.app`
- `https://*.vercel.app`
- `*`
- `+`
- `/*`
- `https://*`
- `www.*`

after giving up, assuming it is some bug in keycloak I discovered their docs...

> Valid Redirect URIs
>
> This is a required field. Enter in a URL pattern and click the + sign
> to add. Click the - sign next to URLs you want to remove. Remember
> that you still have to click the Save button! Wildcards (*) are only
> allowed at the end of a URI, i.e. http://host.com/*
>
> You should take extra precautions when registering valid redirect URI
> patterns. If you make them too general you are vulnerable to attacks.
> See Threat Model Mitigation chapter for more information.

‍♂️...

I'm having a hard time believing they actually did this on purpose.

Surely there *must* be a way to allow login from dynamically generated urls for preview deployments?

Comment: could you share your client URLs config (All fields including root URL, valid redirects ...). Afaik Keycloak allows wildcards only at the end of the URL specification

Comment: The ability to specify more robust wildcards for redirect URIs is under discussion [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/9278), but hasn't seen enough attention yet to get prioritised.